# Confusion regarding Ends

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

I am trying to understand the definition of Ends and CoEnds.

I was looking at some examples where I found the following case because of which I have become more confused.

So, here is the example:

Let $G \in [\textbf{C}^{op} \to \textbf{Set}]$, i.e. Let G be a presheaf.
Now, the example talks about: $\int_{B}GB$.

This does not make sense to me. From what I know, Ends are defined on functors from $\textbf{C}^{op} \times \textbf{C}$ to another category **D** which in this case will be **Set**.  How can one even write $\int_{B}GB$?!

I have tried thinking about this for a while and I thought maybe we can apply Yoneda's Lemma on $GB$. So, we will be able to write: $GB \simeq \hat{\textbf{C}}(\textbf{C}(-, B), G)$. So, we will be able to write: $\int_{B}GB \simeq \int_{B}\hat{\textbf{C}}(\textbf{C}(-, B), G)$.

Now, is $\hat{\textbf{C}}(\textbf{C}(-, B), G)$ a functor from $\textbf{C}^{op} \times \textbf{C}$ to **Set**?

I think I am missing something very simple or basic here. Any help with this would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: $\int_B GB$ is just the limit of $G$; what is the source of this example?

Comment: Yes, I realize that it is probably just the limit. But, why is it written like that though?

Comment: No idea! That's why I asked for the origin of the example :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\int_BGB$ stands for $\int_B\tilde G(B,B)$ where $\tilde G:{\bf C}^{op}\times {\bf C}\to{\bf Set}$ is defined as
$$\tilde G(A,B):=GA\ \text{ and }\ \tilde G(f,g):=Gf\,.$$
One readily sees that it's indeed a functor, e.g. by observing that $\tilde G=G\circ\pi_1$ where $\pi_1:{\bf C}^{op}\times {\bf C}\to{\bf C}^{op}$ is the projection on the first coordinate.

As commented by Fosco, one can prove that $\int_B\tilde G(B,B)$ is just the limit of $G$ in $\bf Set$.